# parse XML in Python - find child

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to write a Python script that will go through Rows and put them into my database

This is a structure of my xml:

```
Root>
    -<SvcNf>
        -<PersonNf>
            -<PersonList>
                -<Row>
                    <SysName>MI8</SysName>
                     <ServerDt>2016-10-28 03:00:12 +03:00</ServerDt>
                     <UID>9457A55E17341AA7ASDEDS057A8BFFF3</UID>
                     <PersID>007</PersID>
                     <Emp_name>James Bond</Emp_name>
                     <EventID>25</EventID>
                     <EventTXT>Drinking alcohol</EventTXT>
                     <CauseEventID>03</CauseEventID>
                     <CauseEventTXT>Martini with vodka</CauseEventTXT>
                     <EventBegda>2017-10-18</EventBegda>
                     <EventEndda>2017-10-18</EventEndda>
                     <AccrualsSum>171.0</AccrualsSum>
                     <AccrualsProz>0.0</AccrualsProz>
                     <AccrualsName>Chinees_</AccrualsName>
                     <OrderNum>P-336</OrderNum>
                     <Perg>0</Persg>
                     <Perk>15</Persk>
                     <Awart/>
                 </Row>
                 -<Row>
                     .....
                 </Row>
                <Row/>
            </PersonList>
        </PersonNf>
    </SvcNf>
</Root>
```

So, when i use this code to Parse XML:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    root = ET.parse(events).getroot()
    nodes = root.findall("Row")
    for node in nodes:
            print(node.text)
```

Result goes to a null

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT**

The nominal Row value is

***['MI8', '2016-10-28 03:00:12 +03:00', '9457A55E17341AA7ASDEDS057A8BFFF3', etc]***

Comment: post how should look the nominal Row value

Comment: `findall` with a bare tag only finds elements that are **direct** children of the element. Try `root.findall('.//Row')`

Comment: after it - results is None

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `node.text` by `[child.text for child in node]`. At the end you need just simply use `join` function to convert the list into a string.

https://repl.it/N144/1

```
root = ET.fromstring("""<Root>
    <SvcNf>
        <PersonNf>
            <PersonList>
                <Row>
                     <SysName>MI8</SysName>
                     <ServerDt>2016-10-28 03:00:12 +03:00</ServerDt>
                     <UID>9457A55E17341AA7ASDEDS057A8BFFF3</UID>
                     <PersID>007</PersID>
                     <Emp_name>James Bond</Emp_name>
                     <EventID>25</EventID>
                     <EventTXT>Drinking alcohol</EventTXT>
                     <CauseEventID>03</CauseEventID>
                     <CauseEventTXT>Martini with vodka</CauseEventTXT>
                     <EventBegda>2017-10-18</EventBegda>
                     <EventEndda>2017-10-18</EventEndda>
                     <AccrualsSum>171.0</AccrualsSum>
                     <AccrualsProz>0.0</AccrualsProz>
                     <AccrualsName>Chinees_</AccrualsName>
                     <OrderNum>P-336</OrderNum>
                     <Persg>0</Persg>
                     <Persk>15</Persk>
                     <Awart/>
                 </Row>
                <Row/>
            </PersonList>
        </PersonNf>
    </SvcNf>
</Root>""")

nodes = root.findall(".//Row")
for node in nodes:
  print node # print node object
  print(node.text) # print nothing
  print [child.text for child in node] # print child text (as list)
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an invalid XML :

```
 <PersID>007</TabNum>
 <Emp_name>James Bond</FIO>
```

Try to fix your XML :

```
 <PersID>007</PersID>
 <Emp_name>James Bond</Emp_name>
```

Comment: I Fix it, its my mistake

Answer (score 0):

With the XML already sanitised and the XML  selector you will have what you want:

```
events = b'''
<Root>
    <SvcNf>
        <PersonNf>
            <PersonList>
                <Row>
                    <SysName>MI8</SysName>
                     <ServerDt>2016-10-28 03:00:12 +03:00</ServerDt>
                     <UID>9457A55E17341AA7ASDEDS057A8BFFF3</UID>
                     <PersID>007</PersID>
                     <FIO>James Bond</FIO>
                     <EventID>25</EventID>
                     <EventTXT>Drinking alcohol</EventTXT>
                     <CauseEventID>03</CauseEventID>
                     <CauseEventTXT>Martini with vodka</CauseEventTXT>
                     <EventBegda>2017-10-18</EventBegda>
                     <EventEndda>2017-10-18</EventEndda>
                     <AccrualsSum>171.0</AccrualsSum>
                     <AccrualsProz>0.0</AccrualsProz>
                     <AccrualsName>Chinees_</AccrualsName>
                     <OrderNum>P-336</OrderNum>
                     <Perg>0</Perg>
                     <Perk>15</Perk>
                     <Awart/>
                </Row>                 
                <Row/>
            </PersonList>
        </PersonNf>
    </SvcNf>
</Root>
'''

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring(events)
nodes = root.findall(".//Row")
#[<Element 'Row' at 0x00C217E0>, <Element 'Row' at 0x00C216C0>]
```